# How to split a string into entered length string array in VB.net

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, user-input, string-length

I have a string which is being entered by user, length depends on the length of entered string.
In another field user needs to type a number of how many equal parts he wants to get out of that string.

For example:

```
Dim unos As String = "Jedna duga linija teksta koju zelim prelomiti na dijelove"
```

Now I want to split this into string array. Each part of this string depends on entered number of parts, example

`EDIT:`

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim unos As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim brLinija As Integer = TextBox2.Text
        Dim unosNiz As New List(Of String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(unos.Length / brLinija) - 1
            unosNiz.Add(unos.Substring(i, unos.Length / brLinija))
        Next
        For Each s As String In unosNiz
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text & s & vbCrLf
        Next
    End Sub
```

brLinija is integer entered by user (number of lines of string array)

`User entered number of lines: 4`

Current output:

```
Jedna duga lin
edna duga lini
dna duga linij
na duga linija
a duga linija 
 duga linija t
duga linija te
uga linija tek
ga linija teks
a linija tekst
 linija teksta
linija teksta 
inija teksta k
nija teksta ko
Jedna duga lin
edna duga lini
dna duga linij
na duga linija
a duga linija 
 duga linija t
duga linija te
uga linija tek
ga linija teks
a linija tekst
 linija teksta
linija teksta 
inija teksta k
nija teksta ko
```

Output I want:

```
jedna duga lini
ja teksta koju
zelim prelomiti
na dijelove
```

I'm just confused how I'm supposed to split this string properly into a substrings.

Thanks

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime. I can tell it is not on now because this line `Dim brLinija As Integer = TextBox2.Text` would not compile.

Comment: After I've done that I got these errors:
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'.
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'Double'

Comment: @Mary Do you not also have `Option Explicit` *On* and `Option Infer` *Off* as defaults? Yes, abstract type situations often require the latter to be turned on - tho there're ways around that if you can live with using `Object` instead - I think it has merit.

Comment: @SteveCinq Actually I have all 3 on. Infer just save a bit of typing. I you hold your cursor over the "inferred" variable you will see that it has a valid type. I really dislike using Object.

Comment: @Wolfhrat Yes, those are errors you need to correct to avoid runtime errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you probably simply want an equal number of chars per line. The last line can instead contain just the *remainder*.

You can iterate the number of lines specified (provided that the number can be parsed to an integer, so use [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to validate the input), then divide the string length in chars by the number of lines and take that number of chars per iteration.

Something like this:

```
Imports System.Linq

' You should also check whether the TextBox.Text contains any chars
Dim unos As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim brLinija As Integer = 0

If (Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, brLinija)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input")
    Return
End If

Dim charPerPart = CInt(Math.Ceiling(unos.Length / brLinija))
Dim unosNiz As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 0 To brLinija - 1
    unosNiz.Add(String.Concat(unos.Skip(charPerPart * i).Take(charPerPart)))
Next
```

It generates this output:

```
Jedna duga lini
ja teksta koju 
zelim prelomiti
 na dijelove
```